# How to automatically approve LogicApp Send Approval Email after 24 hours of no response?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I have a LogicApp that sends out an Approval Email. If there is no response within 24 hours I want to automatically approve it and continue with the workflow. The LogicApp currently stays stuck on the 'Send Approval Email' waiting for a reply.

How do I automatically approve the email after 24 hours within the LogicApps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, Azure Logic App does not have actions that can automatically approve your approval email.

But you can handle the follow-up actions after 24 hours, regardless of whether the email is approved or not. One solution is to set the timeout for `Send approval email` action.

You can first click `···` in the upper right corner, and then click `Settings`:

[image]

The values you can use for this setting are a duration in [ISO 8601 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations). Below you can find some examples:

```
PT30M - 30 minutes
P1D - 1 day
P5D - 5 days
```

Then set the timeout value to `P1D`:

[image]

In order to be able to run the following actions after the `Send approval email` timeout, you need to set [Configure run after](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-exception-handling#customize-run-after-behavior):

[image]

[image]

With this setting, if the email is not approved within 24 hours after sending the approval email, the Azure logic app will continue to execute the following actions.